Algebraic Variety formed by the set of all quadruples of points in P^1
Excerpt from Kock Quantum Cohomology
Hi,
I'm having trouble understanding this passage in Kock's Invitation to Quantum Cohomology.I'm not sure why the set of all quadruples can be described as $(\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \times  \mathbb{P}^1) \backslash\text{diagonals}$. Specifically, why are diagonals disallowed?
Edit: If someone can also explain why MathJax isn't working for my question that would also be great. I'm new to MathSE.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

See the edits for the fix of your MathJax. “Quadruples” connotes four distinct points. Note they say so explicitly. Diagonals of various sorts allow repetitions.

@TedShifrin After speaking with a peer, I was also told that the process of disallowing diagonals is the same as having a quadruple of distinct points. I'm sure it's something simple, but I need a push on visualizing this.

What do you think is the diagonal of, say, $X\times X$?

I guess I'm actually confused about the meaning of diagonal in this context. I'm learning this topic as part of an undergraduate research experience so there's a bit of a leap in setting. Answering your question, a double in $X \times X$ would be two distinct points $(x_1, x_2)$; explicitly $x_1 \neq x_2$. What should I interpret as a diagonal?

@TedShifrin Thanks, it seems like my question is answered directly from the definition of a diagonal. Clearly a diagonal of $X \times X$ is simply a double $(x,x)$ for $x \in X$!

The use of the term "diagonals" here is common but confusing enough that it's worth explaining. If $X$ is a set (we can work much more generally than this but sets are good enough for now) then the map
$$\Delta_X : X \ni x \mapsto (x, x) \in X^2$$
is the diagonal map of $X$, and its image, consisting of the points $(x, x) \in X^2$, is also called the diagonal and also denoted $\Delta_X$. The reason it's called that is that when $X = [0, 1]$ is an interval we have that $X^2 = [0, 1]^2$ is a square and its diagonal in the above sense is one of the diagonals of this square in the usual sense.
The complement of the diagonal $X^2 \setminus \Delta_X$ is the set of points $(x, y) \in X^2$ such that $x \neq y$; in other words, it's the set of pairs of distinct points in $X$.
This genreralizes to tuples as follows: there is a subset of $X^n$ called the fat diagonal $\Delta_X^n$ consisting of points $(x_1, \dots x_n) \in X^n$ such that some pair of coordinates $x_i = x_j$ are equal. The complement of the fat diagonal $X^n \setminus \Delta_X^n$ (sometimes called the (ordered) configuration space $\text{Conf}_n(X)$) is then the set of $n$-tuples of distinct points in $X$. Take the time to try to see visually what the fat diagonal looks like for $X = [0, 1], n = 3$, where $X^3$ is a cube.
Kock's construction takes $X = \mathbb{P}^1, n = 4$. In the case of varieties it is possible to say more than just that we have a set: namely, the fat diagonal is a closed subvariety (it is the union of the closed subvarieties $\Delta_{ij} = \{ x_i = x_j \}$ given by the condition that two specific coordinates are equal), so its complement is an open subvariety. Similarly if $X$ is a manifold then so is $\text{Conf}_n(X)$.

Thanks for the answer, Qiaochu! This pretty much answers everything.
